# React Context API passing values to child components does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to ReactJS and Context APIs/Hooks. I have a basic app where the parent functional component passes  values to 3 buttons. But the problem is that I see the default value ("welcome") on the buttons and not the values that I set in the context.

Context.js:

```
import React, {  useState, useContext, useReducer  } from 'react';

const initalDBStates = {Couchbase:[],MongoDB:[],Cassandra:[], jobId: null, results:[],activeDBName: "Welcome"}

export  const AppContext = React.createContext(initalDBStates);
```

TestGrid.js:

```
import React, {  useState, useContext, useReducer  } from 'react';
import DBButton from './DBButton';

import {AppContext} from "./Context";

const TestGrid = () =>  {

  const context = useContext(AppContext)

  const setActiveDBName = (activeDBName) => {
    setDBState({...dbState, activeDBName: activeDBName})
  }

  const [dbState,setDBState] = useState({...context, updateJobId:updateJobId,updateResults:updateResults,setActiveDBName:setActiveDBName })



        return(
            <AppContext.Provider value={dbState}>
            <div class="dls-gray-02-bg pad " style={{height: '100%', minHeight: '100vh',}}>
            <div class="row stack-a">
                <div class="display-inline-block">
                    <DBButton onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("Couchbase")}/>

                    <DBButton onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("Cassandra")}/>

                    <DBButton onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("MongoDB")}/>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </AppContext.Provider>

    )


}
export default TestGrid;
```

FInally DBBUtton.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {AppContext} from "./Context";

const colors = {"Couchbase":"deep-blue", "MongoDB":"green","Cassandra":"bright-blue"};
function DBButton()   {


        return(
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {
                    (value) => {
                        let buttonClassName =  "btn btn-contextual dls-" + colors[value.activeDBName];
                        let padClassName = "pad-3 dls-"+ colors[value.activeDBName] + "-bg";
                      return(  
                    <div className="margin-b">
                        <div className={padClassName}>
                            <button className={buttonClassName}>{value.activeDBName}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>)

                }
                }
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )


}
export default DBButton;
```

The 3 buttons should display Couchbase, Cassandra and MongoDB, but instead, they're showing the default white color and the "Welcome" default value i used to initialize the context. Can someone please help me with this? Can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your project is currently working:

You're initializing context with "Welcome" as the activeDBName, and the buttons are set to show the current value of activeDBName, which is why they all show "Welcome". You're passing a method that changes the value of activeDBName as a prop called "onClick" to each button, but the button component doesn't make use of the onClick prop (or any props), so nothing happens when you click the buttons.

If you change your code so that your button component passes props.onClick to the actual `<button>` element as its onClick prop, clicking the button will call the setActiveDBName method and set activeDBName to the given value. Clicking the topmost button will change activeDBName to "Couchbase", and since the button component displays the current value of activeDBName, this will result in all three buttons displaying "Couchbase". If you click the second button, all three buttons will display "Cassandra".

To make each button show its own text, you need to pass a prop to the button to tell it what it should show, and use that prop in the button text. (You can also use this prop to dynamically generate the buttons' onClick functions.)
You should also use `className` rather than `class` on your react elements.

I assume there's some additional CSS you haven't included, since currently the only styling that's being applied is on `style={{height: '100%', minHeight: '100vh',}}` on the div in TestGrid.

I've put together a sandbox showing the changes I mentioned above with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-kilby-zomb6?file=/src/DBButton.js

Comment: Appreciate the answer Shannon, but why am I passing props when I am using Context APIs? I thought the whole point of using Context is to stop using props.

Comment: The point of Context is so that if you want to share values between many components (particularly at several levels of nesting), you can do so without passing the same prop through several layers of components or using a state container like Redux--not to remove the use of props altogether. If you want to make the custom button component reusable but show its own text, you still need to tell each instance what its text should be. If you wanted all of the buttons to show the same text, you could use Context.